# Safari can't inspect ionic cordova app in simulator

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode6, ionic-framework, safari-web-inspector

Now I am writing ionic app. I have upgraded `OS X` and `XCode` to newer.

In previous versions, I had debug the ionic app by using safari inspector. But in the new version`(Safari Version 8.0.5 (10600.5.17), XCode Version 6.3.1 (6D1002))`, I can not debug my app by using Safari Inspector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safari seems to work instability sometimes. After this question, I got above problem several times.
At that times, I did restart my mac, then, Safari return to normal working and I could debug via Safari.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had to restart Safari, then open an actual website (NOT just the 'new tab home')